# HDMI x UBUNTU(mantic minotaur) 23.10

Tags: hdmi, 23.10

I updated Ubuntu to 23.10 (mantic minotaur).. and I no longer have a connection to my HDMI, I no longer have 2 monitors... how to solve this? ubuntu 23.10

Comment: What are your graphics cards? AMD or NVIDIA or INTEL or MATROX or something else?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.